# Is it possible to create an application that can control other apps?

Tags: macos, applications, root

Is it possible to get the privilege of an application to control the system and the other apps?

For example, I can ask the application I created to control Outlook, write an email, and send it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply said: yes. There are several Q&As about this on this site already, you may also want to look at AppleScript, Automator, Shortcuts and third-party tools like Keyboard Maestro.

Comment: I have a question : The OP mentions that they want to *create* an app, is this answer really answering this?

Comment: @thinkr "Application" means different things for different people (and both AppleScript and Automator can be turned into "proper" applications). The example given (send mail) can be done with all the tools listed.

Comment: Thanks for explaining :-)